# MYSQL Delete from Table using list of objects

Tags: mysql, list

I have an array of objects (index,id) where each field corresponds to a column in a table. I want a single query where I can delete the row.

I know that you can write a for loop, and then delete each row manually.
`sqlStrings = [] for value in array: sqlStrings.push(f"DELETE FROM table WHERE index = {value.index} AND id = {value.id} ")` 
However, I think this is a poor solution because it's lots of little queries.

I could break the object into two arrays and try and delete the list, but I do not think this works. Say I have two records I want to delete one being id = 1, index = 2 (1.2) and id = 2 and index = 1, (2.1). If I were to make two lists where the condition is WHERE index IN (1,2) and id IN (1,2), this would delete 2.2 or 1.1, which I do not want.

Can this be written more efficiently than a for loop?